# Redirect to login view when logout button is clicked in different app

Tags: django

There are two apps in my Django project: `account` and `boards`.
In `account`, I have `login` and `logout` views as following:

```
#account/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .forms import LoginForm


def user_login(request):
    login_msg = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = login_form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request,
                                username=cleaned_data['username'],
                                password=cleaned_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)    
                    return redirect('boards:home_board')
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'login_form': login_form, 'login_msg': login_msg})


def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

```
#account/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

There is only a `login` template, no `logout` template. The intention is to redirect back to the `login` template when  `logout` event happens.

In the other app `boards`, in the template `home_board`, there is a `Logout` button as following:

```
home_board.html

<div id="nav-bar">&nbsp;
    <button id="logout-button" class="nav-bar-button">Logout</button>
</div>
```

How do I call the view function `account/logout` when this button is clicked, either through Javascript or inline `onclick`? There is no `url` to pass to an `onclick` here.

Note that if I do this:

```
<button id="logout-button" class="nav-bar-button" onclick="location.href='{% url 'account:login' %}'">
      Logout
</button>
```

It will redirect to the login view, but the user is not actually logged out. I need the user to be logged out (by calling `account/user_logout()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `account/urls.py` why not add the `logout` view then refer to that view when the button is clicked?

```
#account/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Now within your `home_board.html`:

```
<button id="logout-button" class="nav-bar-button" onclick="location.href='{% url 'account:logout' %}'">
      Logout
</button>
```

As your `logout` view will actually logout the user and also redirect them to the login page.

In addition, you could use a anchor tag as the button as well...

```
<a class="nav-bar-button" id="logout-button" href="{% url 'account:logout' %}" role='button'></a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did think of it. But I thought since the path ```\logout``` is never used, I was wondering if I can just redirect to the ```\login``` path. But this works.